# Connection refused on my git's depot

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, capistrano

I installed Capistrano for Website deployment and SSH Key for connect to my webserver.

I can connect on my server with SSH Key with " git@myip -p 9325 ".

But, when I went to deploy, I have this error "Connection refused" (ip, user, port and depot git is true) :

```
  01 git ls-remote --heads ssh://git@myip:9325/var/www/depotsGit/project.git/
  01 ssh: connect to host myip port 9325: Connection refused
  01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  01 and the repository exists.
```

Can you help me ? SOrry for my bad english, I'm french ^^

Comment: Although not a coding problem, the problem faced here doesn't seem like it's quite about general purpose computing.  Anything that involves registering SSH keys with github is likely to be the work of a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your machine with Github in order to do this.  Try going here to register your machine with Github:

- Go to your repository's Github account or organization
- Click the account icon in the upper right corner of the page
- Choose 'Settings'
- Choose 'SSH and GPG keys' from the menu on the left
- Click 'New SSH key'
- Add a title for the key, preferably the machine name, so that you can identify it later
- On the machine that has the connection refused, follow the instructions in the Github [generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) help page.
- Paste the SSH key that you generated from the previous step
- Save the new Key information

At that point, you should be able to connect to Github from your Capistrano deployment.